# Android intents: a listview with menu and submenu

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

Hi, Everyone. I would like to display a sub menu when I click a specific item. For instance, clicking <kbd>Play Video</kbd> shows a sub menu with 2 more items: <kbd>Play It</kbd> and <kbd>Show playlist</kbd>.

Is it possible that this sub menu appears like a "dropdown menu" or a "dialog"?

This is the code I'm working with:

```
package com.examples.youtubeapidemo;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeIntents;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.examples.youtubeapidemo.adapter.DemoArrayAdapter;
import com.examples.youtubeapidemo.adapter.DemoListViewItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A sample activity which shows how to use the {@link YouTubeIntents} static
 * methods to create Intents that navigate the user to Activities within the
 * main YouTube application.
 */

public final class IntentsDemoActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    // This is the value of Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY for API level 11 and above.
    private static final String EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY = "android.intent.extra.LOCAL_ONLY";
    private static final String VIDEO_ID = "-Uwjt32NvVA";
    private static final String PLAYLIST_ID = "PLF3DFB800F05F551A";
    private static final String USER_ID = "Google";
    private static final int SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST = 1000;

    private List<DemoListViewItem> intentItems;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intents_demo);

        intentItems = new ArrayList<DemoListViewItem>();
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Play Video", IntentType.PLAY_VIDEO));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Open Playlist",
                IntentType.OPEN_PLAYLIST));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Play Playlist",
                IntentType.PLAY_PLAYLIST));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Open User", IntentType.OPEN_USER));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Open Search Results",
                IntentType.OPEN_SEARCH));
        intentItems
                .add(new IntentItem("Upload Video", IntentType.UPLOAD_VIDEO));

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.intent_list);
        DemoArrayAdapter adapter = new DemoArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, intentItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        TextView youTubeVersionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_version_text);
        String version = YouTubeIntents.getInstalledYouTubeVersionName(this);
        if (version != null) {
            String text = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.youtube_currently_installed), version);
            youTubeVersionText.setText(text);
        } else {
            youTubeVersionText
                    .setText(getString(R.string.youtube_not_installed));
        }
    }

    public boolean isIntentTypeEnabled(IntentType type) {
        switch (type) {
        case PLAY_VIDEO:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntent(this);
        case OPEN_PLAYLIST:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolveOpenPlaylistIntent(this);
        case PLAY_PLAYLIST:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayPlaylistIntent(this);
        case OPEN_SEARCH:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolveSearchIntent(this);
        case OPEN_USER:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolveUserIntent(this);
        case UPLOAD_VIDEO:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolveUploadIntent(this);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        IntentItem clickedIntentItem = (IntentItem) intentItems.get(position);

        Intent intent;
        switch (clickedIntentItem.type) {
        case PLAY_VIDEO:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(this,
                    VIDEO_ID, true, false);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case OPEN_PLAYLIST:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createOpenPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case PLAY_PLAYLIST:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case OPEN_SEARCH:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createSearchIntent(this, USER_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case OPEN_USER:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createUserIntent(this, USER_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case UPLOAD_VIDEO:
            // This will load a picker view in the users' gallery.
            // The upload activity is started in the function onActivityResult.
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null).setType("video/*");
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent returnedIntent) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST:
                Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createUploadIntent(this,
                        returnedIntent.getData());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, returnedIntent);
    }

    private enum IntentType {
        PLAY_VIDEO, OPEN_PLAYLIST, PLAY_PLAYLIST, OPEN_USER, OPEN_SEARCH, UPLOAD_VIDEO;
    }

    private final class IntentItem implements DemoListViewItem {

        public final String title;
        public final IntentType type;

        public IntentItem(String title, IntentType type) {
            this.title = title;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return isIntentTypeEnabled(type);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDisabledText() {
            return getString(R.string.intent_disabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have You tried http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu ?

Comment: I've tried. I didn't get it. I'm a newbie. I just wanted clicking on "Play Video" appears two options to choose: "open a playlist" or "play a playlist". Can anyone adjust this code that I'm working with to what I'm trying to do? Please :/

Answer (score 0):

You might try to implement it like the following code:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    final MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.play_video:
                    //intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(this,
                    //        VIDEO_ID, true, false);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "play video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.show_playlist:
                    //intent = YouTubeIntents.createOpenPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "show playlist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

with actions.xml in res/menu folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/play_video"
          android:title="Play Video"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/show_playlist"
          android:title="Show playlist" />
</menu>
```

It's actually just similar to way mentioned in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)